# Svelte app not finding public images and scripts -- why?

Tags: javascript, html, svelte

I'm starting out with Svelte.  I'm given an application that already works, and am trying to add some functionality to it as a learning exercise.  My changes are failing to find JS and PNG files.

The important -- I claim -- part of what I'm doing is in App.svelte:

```
[SNIP]
<svelte:head>
    <script src="../jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./chessboard-1.0.0.js" on:load={chessLoaded}></script>
</svelte:head>

<main>
    <img src="./logo.png" alt="Vue logo"/>
    <h1>Svelte Pod 2</h1>
[SNIP]
```

Where did I put the JS and PNG files?  So far I put them in the same directory as package.json, and in public.  The rendered page at http://localhost:8082 says it can't find the resources.  And when I ask for the resource directly, such as through "http://localhost:8082/chessboard-1.0.0.js", I get a 404 response.

How do I arrange things so that my files are seen and loaded?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE** ON Sept 8:

Because the discussion has wandered to 'It works for me on a Hello World app', I'm redirecting my failure to the Mozilla version, found at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Client-side_JavaScript_frameworks/Svelte_getting_started

To the code I found there I prepended the svelte:head code, ending up like this:

```
<svelte:head>
    <script src="./jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./chessboard-1.0.0.js"></script>
</svelte:head>

<script>
    export let name;
</script>

<main>
    <h1>Hello {name}!</h1>
    <p>Visit the <a href="https://svelte.dev/tutorial">Svelte tutorial</a> to learn how to build Svelte apps.</p>
</main>

<style>
  [SNIP]
</style>
```

The only place where the svelte:head wanted to find the "./chessboard-1.0.0.js" link at was in the moz-todo-svelte/public directory.  I don't know where Chris G put his jquery file.  I'm not sure if jquery is perhaps already part of the Svelte stack.

Now, my original problem is more complex than I first let on.  I'm trying to add the chessboard feature to a sample program I'm required to work with.  In its root package.json, this sample compiles four workspaces:

- A base layout responds to port 8080
- Svelte 1 has index.ts responding to port 8081
- Svelte 2 has index.ts responding to port 8082
- A Vue layout responds to port 8083

Something of a mess, I think, but that is my territory.  I want to add the chessboard feature to Svelte 2 (port 8082).  I need to get my Svelte 2 to find the chessboard JS file.

I tried putting the chessboard JS file everywhere.  In the root directory, in the root /public, in the Svelte 2 root directory, in **its** /public, etc.  Nothing has worked so far.

So, where does "./chessboard-1.0.0.js" belong so it can be found?

Comment: What do you see in the rollup logs? When I put your svelte:head in the hello world app and the jQuery file in public, then save the app file, it recompiles, shows `[18:42:34] 200 ─ 1.48ms ─ /jquery-3.6.0.min.js` and apparently inserts jQuery into the bundle.js file

Comment: When I run npm start, I see "[svelte-preprocess] The file  "C:\Dev\Micros\podium-svelte-vue-poc-chess\svelte-micro-2\src\jquery-3.6.0.min.js" was not found.".  I've looked through the node_modules, in @rollup and in various rollup*, for something that would be a log file.  Where should a log file be?

Comment: You have `..` before the file, so svelte looks in `src` for it, as per the line you cite. Yet you have it in the main folder and in public but not in `src`. Use `src="./jquery-3.6.0.min.js"` and it should find it. The log I'm talking about is the one you're looking at, the one telling you *exactly* where svelte is looking for the file

Comment: The log I should look for is the result of running npm start?

Comment: That ../ for jquery comes from thrashing about.  My system fails to find things even with ./, such as chessboard*.js.  I'll look at hellow world, and my logging.  I'll need a couple of days to get back to this, as I'm called away to a "want it now" project.